# Get a value of a key from an array of inconsistent file paths

Tags: javascript, json

this is the file paths I have:

usr/xxx/1/101

usr/xxx/1/105

usr/xxx/1/188
...

usr/xxx/2/202

usr/xxx/2/208
...

And within these file paths, they all have a value of a key that I need, (in my scenario, it will be the URL of imageUrl):

```
{
"timelineList":[{:},{:}],
"currentImage":{"imageUrl":"http://xxx"} 
}
```

May I ask if there is a recommendation on how can I run through all these paths and files and get the imageUrl from each file please?

Answer (score 0):

Wih Java, like this:

```
String[] extension={"json"};
List<File> files=FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/usr/"), extension, true);
```

after this:

```
foreach(File file:files){
   Map content new ObjectMapper(FileUtils.readFileToString(file),Map.class);
    //get imagesfrom map
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have trouble getting images from map. I tried `alert(content["currentImage["imageUrl"]"]);` but it doesn't work... Do I need to use it with the Jackson library or did I do it wrong please? Cheers x

Comment: I think you have missed to write that which language you are using. And my answer was in java( it is because I work with it al lot :) ). Are you lookin for a solution in javascript?

Comment: Hello, Sorry about that but yes I am using js or jQuery :))) x